# File is replicated without reason (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv

First, it's hard to explain. If someone have a better title, feel free to edit/suggest.

So, I am using the next code to delete ROI's from given images.

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import shutil

src = (os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output\\'))

causali = os.listdir(src)  # CREO LISTA CAUSALI-2
causali.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))

for file in enumerate(causali):  # CONTA NUMERO DI FILE CAUSALE

    #import image
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output\\{}'.format(file[1])))
    cv2.imshow('orig',image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    #grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)

    #binary
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    #cv2.imshow('second',thresh)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)

    #dilation
    kernel = np.ones((1,80), np.uint8)
    img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
    #cv2.imshow('dilated',img_dilation)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)

    #find contours
    im2,ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    #sort contours
    sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

    for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
        # Get bounding box
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

        # Getting ROI
        roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        if h < 25:
            clean = cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(255,255,255),-1)


    cv2.imwrite(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output2\\{}.png').format(file[0]), clean)
```

I put a condition if `h < 25` to delete the ROI I don't want to be visible in the final image.

This is source folder..
[image: src]

and this is the output the program give out..

[image: out]

As you can see, file n°8 came out as the n°7. This because the program don't find any ROI in that image which is ok for the condition.

The problem is I don't understand why it replicate the last file he worked (7 ---> 8). How can I fix this ?

In case no ROI is found it should just copy the file, not overwrite it with the last one..

Thanks

Comment: There's a lot of issues with the code currently. Firstly, `cv2.rectangle()` modifies the image in place, it does not pass it as an output. I.e. You shouldn't write `output_img = cv2.rectangle(input_img, ...)`, it's `cv2.rectangle(input_output_image, ...)`. The image you pass in gets actually modified. So even though `output_img = cv2.rectangle(input_img, ...)` *works*, both `output_img` and `input_img` will be identical (I'm assuming that's why you've got double).

Comment: Sorry but I can't get it. The image have to be modified, all ROI which satisfy condition must be covered with a filled in rectangle.
The deisired output is that if image don't have rectangles which is not satisfying condition, then the output image should be as the input, with no modifications.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what I wrote. `cv2.rectangle(img, ...)` *modifies the image you put as the input argument*. You shouldn't do `clean = cv2.rectangle(img, ...)` as then `clean` and `img` will be identical. You *should* do `clean = img.copy()`, and then `cv2.rectangle(clean, ...)`. That way `clean` and `img` are not the same. Either way that's not even the main issue. You set `clean = ...` only whenever `h < 25`. So if `h >= 25` you're going to write the *old* clean image again.

Comment: @Link  I check the code, there is no obvious error. But I cannot get your source images, so  cannot do testing. Maybe you should check the filenames variable `causali`.

Comment: @Silencer here are the files: [link](https://nofile.io/f/zOr6SbttPjx/causali.zip).
Tip: working on "h" variable by putting an else if the condition is not satisfied and then give original image to imwrite, seems to work a bit but if I give more than 17 files (for example 200) it stop doing the job.

Comment: @Link I run your code on my pc, this is the result of #8 https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jlkT.png,  of all https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gw5B.png. Strangely, different with your result. And of course, you should copy the image before you do if condition to avoid the clean is invalid.

Comment: @Silencer but 8 and 9 are the same. I think it's the same error as mine, more or less..
Can you post a code snippet of how to put img.copy() ?

Comment: @Link I put my attention on #7 and #8... I'll try

Comment: For example, this is what I tried:
`if h < 25:
        clean = cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(255,255,255),-1)

        cv2.imwrite(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output2\\{}.png').format(file[0]), clean)

    else:
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output2\\{}.png').format(file[0]), image)`

But with more images this fails..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite the code, make copy before every processing,  and fill them with color, now it's more clear:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

causali = os.listdir("causali")
causali.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
print(causali)
for idx, fname in enumerate(causali):
    fname = os.path.expanduser("causali/"+fname)
    print(fname)
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    kernel = np.ones((1,80), np.uint8)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(dilated.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda cnt: cv2.boundingRect(cnt)[0])

    ## make an copy first
    clean = img.copy()
    for i, cnt in enumerate(cnts):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        if h < 25:
            #clean = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(255,255,255),-1)
            clean = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(0,255,0),-1)

    ## save the "clean"
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.expanduser("output/{}.png").format(idx), clean)
```

---

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: LOL, it was just about to add `clean = img.copy()` above the for like @Alexander Reynolds said.
Thanks a lot.